# Make my local database (PostgreSQL) works in UTC time with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

How to make my local PostgreSQL database works in UTC timezone.

My local UTC offset is +04:00

I'm making an app and want users from different timezones work with the same data. So storing it in UTC timezone is the right thing, I think. And Heroku by default store data in UTC, but it's difficult to debug with different database timezones in development and in production.

Comment: Rails will assume dates/times to and from the DB are UTC by default - what exactly makes this hard for development?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of factors here.  You're using the Rails timestamp value for these columns, correct?  This will be stored as a Postgres timestamp without timezone as UTC.

If you're trying to change the values in the psql or other consoles, they will be localized based on your postgres config.

For example, my postgresql.conf has:

```
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
#intervalstyle = 'postgres'
timezone = 'US/Eastern'
```

If you install Postgresql using homebrew or another packaging system, these should be set automatically.